# How to split a string in two words with a separator excluding the separator himself in Javascript using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to separate a string in two words by a separator in Javascript using a regex.

This is the pattern that I'm trying:

```
(.*)(?=\s*[/]\s*)(.*)
```

The separator can be:

```
"/"
" /"
"/ "
```

Considering this test case:

```
word1 / word2
```

My actual result is:

```
"word1 "
"/ word2"
```

How can I obtain the two tokens:

```
word1
word2
```

Furthermore, I want to match also a single word (if the string is only "word1", "word1" has to be matched.

Thanks.

Comment: [`([^\/\s+]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/zT8mF0/1)

Answer (score 2):

You can do simple `split`:

```
var words = 'word1 / word2'.split(/\s*\/\s*/)
//=> ["word1", "word2"]
```

Spaces are optional on either side so even these will work:

```
words = 'word1 /word2'.split(/\s*\/\s*/)
//=> ["word1", "word2"]

words = 'word1/word2'.split(/\s*\/\s*/)
//=> ["word1", "word2"]

words = 'word1/ word2'.split(/\s*\/\s*/)
//=> ["word1", "word2"]
```

Comment: another :- simply split on `/` and then trim

Comment: `str.split('/').map(e => e.trim())` @rock321987

Comment: @AlessandroC: It is indeed splitting by regex `/\s*\/\s*/` which means `/` with optional 0 or more spaces on either side

Answer (score 0):

The alternative solution using `String.match` function:

```
var str = 'word1 / word2/ word3/word4 /word5',
    words = str.match(/(?=\/\s?)?(\w+)(?=\s?\/)?/g);

console.log(words); // ["word1", "word2", "word3", "word4", "word5"]
```